# beautifulsoup find the div inside div

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to find get `acckey` value,I don't know how to write `python` code with `bs4`

```
<div class="data_record">
    <div class="result_select"></div>
    <div class="result_level"></div>

    <div class="result_digital">
        <a class="act_content_display" acckey="69c19f8552dfdccb526f4728cf4e5cb6" title="檢視詳目頁">
            <span class="material-icons">picture_as_pdf</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing complicated. You need to specify in the Find method the tag and class you are looking for. Further from this tag to receive the necessary attribute. In our case, this is acckey

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_Text = '''<div class="data_record">
    <div class="result_select"></div>
    <div class="result_level"></div>

    <div class="result_digital">
        <a class="act_content_display" acckey="69c19f8552dfdccb526f4728cf4e5cb6" title="檢視詳目頁">
            <span class="material-icons">picture_as_pdf</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_Text, 'lxml')
print(soup.find('a', class_='act_content_display').get('acckey'))
```

OUTPUT:

```
69c19f8552dfdccb526f4728cf4e5cb6
```

Comment: This is not the way I want to do it.

Comment: @chino what way do you need?

Comment: #获取 acckey
acckey_list = []
num_list = []
for items in soup.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'data_record'}):
    result_title = items.find('div',attrs={'class':'result_title'})
    num = items.find('span',attrs={'class':'meta_num'}).text.replace("."," ")
    num_list.append(num)
    acckey_list.append(result_title.a['acckey'])